# print address of dynamic memory, stored in an array of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, g++, dynamic-memory-allocation

How do I print the data stored in the `char*` array [In C, we use `%p` to display addresses].

```
char * tokens[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
tokens[i] = new char[5];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
std::cout<<"Address: "<<tokens[i]<<std::endl;

/*Add data in the array*/

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
delete[] tokens[i];
```

This gives me,

```
Address: 
Address: 
Address: 
Address: 
Address:
```

I understand that must be because, `tokens[i]` is the start address of a string so `cout` prints the string which as of now is empty.

What do I have to typecast `tokens[i]` to at `std::cout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator<<` is overloaded for `char*` and it assumes you have a null-terminated character array that you want printed.  Cast it to a `void*` to get the value of the pointer instead:

```
std::cout << "Address: " << static_cast<void*>(tokens[i]) << std::endl;
```

See running code here: https://ideone.com/9Cst8F